# problem to access a model property from _layout.cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Check the code bellow. I am using c# mvc5 and trying to loop over a model from `_Layout.cshtml` but when i try to access `AllModuleTypes` property from Model `MainLayoutData` visual studio intellisense shows error: `member cannot be accessed with an instance reference qualify it with a type name instead`. Whats wrong i am doing?

Model:

```cs
public class MainLayoutData
{
    public static List<ModuleTypes> AllModuleTypes { get; set; } 
}
```

Controller:

```cs
public ActionResult Index()
{
    using (var ctx = new TestEntities())
    {
        var modTypes = ctx.ModuleTypes.ToList();
        var mainlayData = new MainLayoutData();
        MainLayoutData.AllModuleTypes = modTypes;

        return View(mainlayData);
    }
}
```

_Layout.cshtml:

```
@model TestProject.ViewModels.MainLayoutData

@foreach (var type in Model.AllModuleTypes)
{
    <option>@type.something</option>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your class just exports a `public static` property, you are not able to access it from an instance. When using the `@model` directive you are expecting an instance of that class in the 'Model' property. Instead, use `@using <name-space-name>` to import the namespace where the class is and then you can access the static property directly `MainLayoutData.AllModuleTypes`.

> Take into account that you may not have a value set in that property. Make sure you have a value or validate before accessing it.

```
@using TestProject.TheClassNamespace

@foreach (var type in MainLayoutData.AllModuleTypes)
{
    <option>@type.something</option>
}
```